# How to forward my domain registered with AWS Route53 to Google My Business?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, google-my-business-api

My domain: [fishercoder.com](http://fishercoder.com/) is registered with AWS Route53.
Now I'd like to configure Google My Business to use this domain.

I searched on [Google's doc](https://support.google.com/business/answer/7032844?hl=en) and found that they do offer clear instructions on how to purchase a new domain through them, for third-party domain they listed instructions for GoDaddy, eNom and Network Solutions, but none for AWS Route53.

I thought it might be similar, so I tried to simulate what I can do on AWS Route 53 console, but didn't find any luck.

Any could share any ideas how to achieve this?

More details:

Right now, when people search "fisher coder", this page shows up: https://ibb.co/pRWjRc9, and if they click `Website`, it'll take them to the default [Google My Business website](https://ibb.co/c8pLcnK) which is not what I desired, I'd like to change it to point to my own domain: [fishercoder.com](http://fishercoder.com/)

Thanks!

Comment: what you want to do exactly ? Google my business page is just to show business page in google map and business information about working hours and review etc

Comment: I'd like to have my own domain be the homepage when people click my Google My Business page.

Comment: You create your s3 bucket for website hosting this will give your link of website. this link you can add in your google business page  like this you want https://ibb.co/Ry8CHMS see on website button click showing page link

Comment: I don't think I'm following what you are saying. Any detailed instructions where/how I add it in Google My Business page? If I could add this S3 link, why cannot I not directly use my own domain? thanks

Comment: Give example what need exactly I am confuse

Comment: I've just added more details into the question, hope that clarifies. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216666/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-fisher-coder).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but it’s not a pretty solution. Not only that but a Google My Business Site (I assume this is what you mean) is so basic it’s not a good website replacement at all. It’s a good free option to set up because it’s free but other than that, it’s meant to keep people in Google, not to help you. You can only map custom domain buy from from business sites option given there.

[image: Custom Domain option]

Here’s how you do it:

Buy a domain wherever you prefer (I like Namecheap but Google Domains is also a good option).
Forward the domain to the Google Sites URL (many registrars will allow you to do this for free).
That’s it!
It’s not a pretty solution nor ideal because the URL of the Google Site will still be the original URL and they won’t stay on your custom domain at all.

So, simple description: if someone types in http://customdomain.com they will get forwarded to your Google URL and remain on that URL. It essentially just forwards to your Google Site, that’s it.

In AWS routes you will get option to forward domain. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/

This all information based on own experiment and study based on below link

Reference info : https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-attach-a-custom-domain-to-a-Google-Sites-website

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see how this could help solve my question.

Comment: And this link: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/ you posted is actually doing the opposite: forwarding a domain registered with AWS to another domain, right? Thanks

Comment: i mention is there is no way to do if you already purchase domain out of google. You have to domain forwarding in amazon route53.

Comment: Yes, what I'm asking is  how I can do domain forwarding either in Amazon Route53 or in GMB.

Comment: DOMAIN forwarding you have to do it aws route 53.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62657704/how-to-redirect-to-a-particular-cname-in-a-cloudfront-distribution/62664631#62664631 see this

Comment: I don't see how that's even related to what I am asking...