# How to redirect to a particular CNAME in a CloudFront Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have 2 CloudFront distributions in AWS, each with its own different certificate. Each has several CNAMEs attached and each CNAME has a corresponding Record Set in Route 53.

Is there a way to redirect one of the URLs to a CNAME in the other CloudFront Distribution?

So for example, if CloudFront Distribution A contains 2 CNAMES, abc.my-old-site.com and 123.my-old-site.com, and CloudFront Distribution B contains 2 CNAMEs, abc.my-new-site.com and 123.my-new-site.com, can I redirect abc.my-old-site.com to abc.my-new-site.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do two ways this :

**First**

1. Create S3 bucket
2. Use this [S3 bucket as website hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)
3. Set website redirect request to abc.my-new-site.com as per screenshot [image: Screenshot1]
4. Set [S3 endpoint in route53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html)
5. If you want to use cloudfront then you can set route53 to cloudfront end point also.

**Second**

1. Domain f[orwarding in route53](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/) against abc.my-old-site.com to abc.my-new-site.com